# Ordenar Array con PHP para generar un listado de menu multilevel

Tags: php, html, mysql, array

Estoy tratando de generar un listado de menu multilevel en PHP pero no he conseguido como hacerlo, quisiera me ayudaran con ejemplos sencillos y ordenar las Categorías y Sub categorías con su titulo, algo así:

- Category 1
- TITLE HERE

  - Category Child 1
  - Category Child 2
  - Category Child 3
  - TITLE HERE

    - Category child 1
    - Category child 2
    - Category child 3
- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

**Tengo un array en PHP:**

```
$data = Array (
    '0' => Array (
        'id' => '1',
        'id_parent' => '',
        'name' => 'Sports'
    ),

    '1' => Array (
        'id' => '2',
        'id_parent' => '1',
        'name' => 'Football'
    ),

    '2' => Array (
        'id' => '3',
        'id_parent' => '1',
        'name' => 'Bascket'
    ),

    '3' => Array (
        'id' => '4',
        'id_parent' => '',
        'name' => 'Health'
    ),

    '4' => Array (
        'id' => '5',
        'id_parent' => '4',
        'name' => 'Nutrition and diet'
    ),

    '5' => Array (
        'id' => '6',
        'id_parent' => '4',
        'name' => 'Beauty Salon'
    ),

    '6' => Array (
        'id' => '7',
        'id_parent' => '',
        'name' => 'Films'
    ),

    '7' => Array (
        'id' => '8',
        'id_parent' => '7',
        'name' => 'Armageddon'
    ),

    '8' => Array (
        'id' => '9',
        'id_parent' => '7',
        'name' => 'Apocalypse'
    ),

    '9' => Array (
        'id' => '10',
        'id_parent' => '',
        'name' => 'News'
    ),

    '10' => Array (
        'id' => '11',
        'id_parent' => '10',
        'name' => 'International'
    ),

    '11' => Array (
        'id' => '12',
        'id_parent' => '11',
        'name' => 'News from Syria'
    ),

    '12' => Array (
        'id' => '13',
        'id_parent' => '11',
        'name' => 'News from Palestine'
    )
);
```

**Tengo una tabla en MySQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_parent` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FK_categories_UNIQUE` (`name`),
  KEY `FK_categories` (`id_parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_categories` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parent`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of categories
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('1', null, 'Sports');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('2', '1', 'Football');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('3', '1', 'Bascket');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('4', null, 'Health');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('5', '4', 'Nutrition and diet');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('6', '4', 'Beauty Salon');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('7', null, 'Films');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('8', '7', 'Armageddon');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('9', '7', 'Apocalypse');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('10', null, 'News');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('11', '10', 'International');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('12', '11', 'News from Syria');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('13', '11', 'News from Palestine');
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda por favor.

Comment: Lo más lógico sería que ordenaras los campos al hacer la consulta select a la base de datos y luego los recorres para mostrarlos. No queda claro si tu problema es la ordenación (por el título se deduciría que es este) o hacer niveles en el menú o ambos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pones el menú en dos formatos, en un formato array y en un formato Base de datos. No sé cual es el que vas a utilizar. Entiendo que el array lo sacas de la base de datos y lo único que falta es convertir el array en el menú.

En este código se utiliza programación recursiva. Se trata de una función que se llama a si misma repetidas veces. En este caso para sacar cada uno de los menus y submenus.

```
function devolverNivelRecursivo( $padre, $data ) {

   $arr = array();    

   // Sacando elementos hijos del padre indicado
   foreach( $data as $elem ) {
       if ( $elem['id_parent'] == $padre) {
           $arr[] = $elem;
       }
   }

   if ( count($arr) > 0 ) {
       echo "\n<ul>\n";
       foreach( $arr as $menu ) {
          echo "<li><span>" . $menu['name'] . "</span>";

          // Busco si el elemento tiene hijos
          devolverNivelRecursivo($menu['id'], $data);

          echo "</li>\n";
       }
       echo "</ul>\n";
   }
}

// Funcion para ordenar el array
function comp($x, $y) {
    if ($x['name'] == $y['name']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($x['name'] < $y['name']) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Ordenamos el menu (sin tener en cuenta niveles) por el campo name
uasort($data, 'comp');

// llamo a la funcion recursiva indicandole padre vacio (raíz)
devolverNivelRecursivo( '', $data );
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, buen día.